# Why does the word "never" not contain an apostrophe?

Tags: negation, apostrophe, contractions

If *never* is a contraction of 'not ever' why does it not have an apostrophe, i.e. why is it not written *n'ever* rather than *never*?

I can understand that the apostrophe has simply fallen out of use, but then why not the same loss of the apostrophe in other negative contractions, e.g. *can't* rather than *cant* or *don't* rather than *dont* etc. Curious.

Comment: But 'never' is ***not*** a contraction of 'not ever'. It's a very old word that appears in - and predates - [Beowulf](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beowulf). Back then (C8-C10?) it was written as  ***næfre***. The negating prefix ***n*** (also ***ne, no, none***) were an integral part of the word(s) long before apostrophes were introduced C18.

Comment: @FumbleFingers You should post this as an answer. (Why are all of the best answers posted as comments?)

Comment: @FracturedRetina: I didn't downvote or closevote, but I don't think it's a very good question. After all, OP could easily have checked the [*etymology of **never***](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=never) and/or the [*history of the apostrophe*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apostrophe)

Comment: @FumbleFingers sometimes a question posted can whet your curiosity and provoke reflections which might not otherwise occur. The question itself may not satisfy the ELU criterion, but your comment is certainly very interesting, and I for one did not know apostrophes date from C18. I also would like to know why the OP claims that *never* is a contraction. Someone must have told him, or did he read it somewhere?

Comment: -1 Beginning the question with the big "If" has rendered it hypothetical. Voting to close as NARQ.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is based on a misconception.

Comment: And for all the curiosity, some homework would have saved you a lot of effort -- the comments so far show.

Comment: The apostrophe in *can't* & *don't* has nothing to do with negation -- it's a signal for a dropped letter, exactly as in *it's*.

Comment: @Mari-Lou, Kris: I partially agree with *both* your positions. I posted my first comment because as Kris says, OP's question is based on a misconception. But I didn't downvote or closevote because as Mari-Lou says, it may directly or indirectly raise some interesting issues.

Comment: @Kris The hypothetical apostrophe in *n'ever* would also indicate dropped letters. And the OP then goes on to ask why the contraction-apostrophe in *can't* has not disappeared as well. He doesn't equate the **apostrophe** with negation; rather it's the letter **n** for *not* which is the negator, and the apostrophe indicates the omission of letters. [A misconception; but given that misconception, the question itself is logical.]

Comment: @Andrew: I don't think anyone is suggesting OP thinks the apostrophe itself indicates negation. All we're saying is that since ***never*** isn't a contraction of ***not ever*** in the first place, you can't really ask why the apostrophe has "disappeared" (A. It was never there anyway - ***n*** was a valid negating prefix long before Modern English arrived).

Comment: @AndrewLeach "And for all the curiosity, some homework would have saved you a lot of effort -- the comments so far show." Need say more?  http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=never https://www.google.com/#q=never+etymology

Answer (score 8):

I'm posting my comment as an answer because I'm not sure there's much else one can say as a direct response to the question as posed (which is based on a misconception).

> 'Never' is not a contraction of 'not ever'. It's a very old word that appears in (and predates) [Beowulf](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beowulf). Back then (C8-C10?) it was written as *næfre*. The negating prefix ***n*** (also ***ne, no, none***) were an integral part of the word(s) long before apostrophes were widely adopted in C18.

The only point I would add is that I know the apostrophe occured in English [as far back as 1559](http://peterviney.wordpress.com/about/elt-articles/apostrophes/). But it wasn't widespread until much later, long after the original *næfre/never* was commonplace.

Comment: so because it's a non- modern english word to your ears and mind it means it's not a contraction?? um, wtf? naefre is itself a contraction of ne and aefre, meaning the same as not ever, and so is the structural and literal equivalent of not ever. so, it's a contraction, of not ever.

Comment: [**never**: *Origin: before 900; Middle English; Old English **nǣfre**, equivalent to **ne** not + **ǣfre** ever. So, not a contraction, but a **translation** or **adaptation.***](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20111127210844AA2PCli). That's how I saw it when I originally posted a comment under the question. Since over a dozen people upvoted the comment, it seemed only reasonable to convert it to an answer. I take your point that the precise meaning of "contraction" might be debatable - but OP clearly assumed the "original" was ***not ever***, which is definitely a misconception.

Comment: This answer is likely as good as the OP is apt to get, will he or nill he.

Comment: @tchrist: OP hasn't returned to ELU since posting the question over a year ago, so I'm not holding my breath waiting for an "acceptance" vote here.