# Confused how to make a sentence in keeping with the context

Tags: grammar, sentence

I have shared a video of a Qur'an recitation on Facebook because it's so melodious to listen to and wanted everyone should listen to it. Can I say it like this below sentence or how can I say it so that it sounds natural.

▪ You can't ever imagine how beautiful a Qur'an recitation can be if you do not listen to it.

Comment: You *wanted everyone **to** listen to it*, not *wanted everyone **should** listen to it*. But this is Off Topic proofreading / writing advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We would usually say the following:

"You can never imagine..."

never is really like saying "not ever" but it's the more natural way to say it.

(It's not actually a contraction of "not ever" see here[.)](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/139646/382302)

Comment: Can I write it like this : You can't even imagine how beautiful a Qur'an recitation can be unless you listen to it.

Comment: You can, and it sounds good, but it has a slightly different connotation. "You can never imagine...unless" means this thing is not possible for you to imagine it. "You can't even imagine...unless" means that not only  do you not know something but you can't even imagine it. Slightly different meaning, but quite legitimate.

Comment: Thanks Binyomin

Comment: I'd appreciate if someone would explain they gave me a downvote; if there is something wrong it would be helpful for me to know so I could improve my answers.